# Publishing from Octomap_server

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone can I publish a 2d projection of the map (occupancy_grid msg) that I loaded on the octomap_server and pass it to map_server or costmap_2d on some topic?
Can you help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105331/publishing-from-octomap_server/) by [Mattia](https://answers.ros.org/users/9221/mattia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The octomap_server already does this for you on the projected_map topic.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mattia](https://answers.ros.org/users/9221/mattia/) on 2013-11-27**:
Ok! So if I publish a map on octomap_server this map will be also automatically passed to costmap_2d?!
Can you help me telling me what have I to write to read a costmap2dRos object from a costmap_2d node while i'm in a new Ros-node created by me?
Thanks a lot for all the answers

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-27**:
It's there to be used, but published on projected_map instead of map to avoid conflicts with another map server running. If you want to used this as the map topic remap projected_map:=map when starting octomap_server. For follow-up questions, please open a new one.